# how to populate select list using hook_form_alter()?

Tags: entities

I wanted to add values to a select list dynamically. Another module generates an array from a web service and I want to use those values to populate a select list in a form using ***hook_form_alter.***

I tried directly adding the options in #options of the field using the following code

```
<?php $form['field_mage_category']['und']['#options']=$arr; ?>
```

The above code adds the options to the select list and returns a value according to the options selected but when the form is loaded again for editing. The option is set to default value and other issue is that when a single option is deleted. The respective value is not getting deleted from the **field_data table.**

I tried using #after-build property to populate the select list.below code is the call to _add_category_select_list function

```
      <?php function main_menu_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
       if($form_id=='main_menu_node_form'){
           form['field_mage_category']['#after_build'] = array('_add_category_select_list');
          } ?>
```

and following is the code in the _add_category_select_list function

```
<?php function _add_category_select_list($element, &$form_state) {
$mlib=new Mlibrary();
$main_category=$mlib->get_main_menu_Categories();
   foreach($main_category as $main){
       $element['und']['#options'] = array($main['category_id'] => $main['Title'])+  $element['und']['#options'];
    }

return ($element);
   } ?>
```

The above code populates the select list but when the option is selected it is not returning any values for the options selected. Can anyone give me a proper way to add #options to select list dynamically using hook_form_alter or any other options that will allow me to add  options from my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method was very close; I wouldn't advise using an `#after_build` function for this simply because it's not necessary.

When you're dealing with field widgets added to forms the actual form elements (textfield, select, checkbox, etc.) are a little further down in the array (see [Why is hook_form_alter() so messy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784) for more info).

In your case this should work:

```
$form['field_mage_category']['und'][0]['value']['#options'] = $arr;
```

Comment: your solution didnt work. The code you mentioned adds an '0' array to the field. but actual options is in the array field_mage_category->['und']['#options']. I am able to add values into this array and the values are getting displayed in the list as well but I the selected value is not getting displayed if the content is loaded again.

Comment: That's a little strange. What type of field/widget are you using for `field_mage_category`?

Comment: I am using list(text) field and Select list widget

Comment: The values are getting displayed in the list with both the codes I have specified in the question. Only thing is that it is not getting displayed when the content is loaded again.

Comment: I have checked the field_data_field_mage_category table in database. For the first method the values are getting added in the table but not getting loaded when the content is opened again. In using #after-build the values are not even getting added to the table.

Comment: Ohh I see what's happening. The `list` field type keeps a list of "allowed values", which you set in the textarea on the field settings page. When Drupal goes to display a field value I imagine it will check that the value is in that "allowed values" list. Since it probably isn't (as you're adding new values to the select list), that's why nothing is being displayed.

Comment: So what is the solution to solve this?

Comment: Moreover I didn set any list of allowed values in the field setting page for the field_mage_category field.

Answer (score 2):

For select field we can use as follows

```
$form['field_task']['und']['#options'] =$arr;
//array('black'=>'black')
```