# How would I change the label of a field in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()?

Tags: entities, hooks

For a Drupal 7 site, I'm trying to alter a form into multi-step and want to change the label of a field based on some answer from the first step, which is the reason for my question.

I tried modifying $form[$field_name]['und']['#title'] but the label gets set back to default sometime after the alter function.  I tried using an after_build function, but maybe I'm using it wrong because it still doesn't change.

Edit: The answer on [Why is hook_form_alter() so messy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7) explains which label I should change.

Comment: Have you tried `$form[$field_name]['und'][0]['value']['#title']`?

Comment: Are you using any other plugins, such as [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) (which is a module worth looking at as an alternative to hook_form_FORM_ID_alter)

Comment: @Clive, I tried that now.  That seems to work when altering the node form.  It is not working when altering the user_register_form.  Weird.  I should be more specific in my question about which form, but I was interested in a general answer to learn what the best way to programmatically modify field labels in D7 should be.

Comment: @StaceyBorsody [This might help](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7)

Comment: @Clive Thanks, that does help.  You don't by chance know where in the process that 'value' (or 'nid') array gets built and if it can be re-built, do you?

Comment: @StaceyBorsody It's buried down in the field API functions, but I don't think that's where you need to look. It might be that another module is altering the form after yours. Have a look at [How to update a module's weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238) to see if that helps

Comment: @Clive initially even I thought that some other module if altering the weight. But the other things like hiding the field work from form alter works perfectly fine. So its not a question of module weight. But for some weird reason the title just doesn't seem to change.

Comment: @StaceyBorsody Isee that you have found your answer. Can you elaborate your answer? I have use case very similar to your but I am not able to find any solution.