# Change the default value of the node reference via hook_alter_form

Tags: forms, users

field_userid is a user reference field with an autocomplete widget

i want to set the default value of this field, but the code below doesn't work

Does anyone can help me?

Thank you very much!

```
 function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
    {
        global $user;


        if($form['#node']->type=="article")
        {   

            $form['#after_build'][]='mymodule_after_build';     


        }
    }

    function mymodule_after_build($form, &$form_state)
    {
        global $user;   

        $form['field_userid']['#default_value'][0]['uid']=$user->uid;

        return $form;
    }
```

Comment: btw, i tried $form['field_userid']['#default_value']['und'][0]['uid']=$user->uid; doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any reason why your code would need to be in an `after_build` function, you would usually put it straight into the form alter hook. At the moment you've got the array keys the wrong way round. Without being able to see the structure of your form it's difficult to say exactly where the correct element is, but one of these should work:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  // Try this one
  $form['field_userid'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#default_value'] = $user->uid;

  // Or this one
  $form['field_userid'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uid']['#default_value'] = $user->uid;
}
```

Comment: "$form['field_userid'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uid']['#default_value'] = $user->uid;"This works, Thank you! But i don't know why? The order of the structure array will affect the result?

Comment: why  $form['field_userid']['#default_value']['und'][0]['uid']=$user->uid doesn't work? Mr.(or Mrs.) Clive ,Could u plz explain for me?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784 might help explain it a bit

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to use `hook_form_alter()` to assign the current user as **entity reference** (not user reference) of node being created.

First I tried this in `hook_form_alter` but did not work:

```
$form['field_userid'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $user->name;
```

Then I decided to use `hook_node_presave()` instead and this is how I assigned user to node created as entity ref:

```
function answers_node_presave($node) {  
  global $user;  
  $node->field_original_author[$node->language][]['target_id'] = $user->uid;  
  $node->field_original_author[$node->language][]['target_type'] = "user";  
}
```

Credit to [Clive's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/37597/10176) that led me to my solution.