# #ajax callback not firing on Select (or other) field

Tags: 7, forms

I am having the exact same problem as described here: http://drupal.org/node/1335568
That is, to repost the OPs question, I have code as shown below. But when I make a change to the select box the 'change' event is not firing. as the callback is not being run.
The author of this module answered but frankly his response makes no sense to me.
His reply:

"These aren't things I should have to handle specifically. Just attach the properties directly 
 to the form element (which are children of select_or_other) in a #pre_render callback.
 You might also be able to do it via #select_ajax and #other_ajax, etc... but that might 
 depend on what phase of the form you are doing it."

A google search on "#select_ajax" only returns the page containing that answer! Also, his idea of a "pre_render" callback doesn't make much sense to me. Is anyone here able to untangle this? Can someone provide an example of possibly how to fix this?

`if ($form['#bundle']=='field_contract_parties'){
    $form['field_select_or_other']['und']['#options'] = load_select_options();
    $ajax_array = array(
                      'callback' => 'my_callback_function',
                      'wrapper' => 'contacts-replace',
                      'event' => 'change',
                    );                
    $form['field_select_or_other']['und']['#ajax'] = $ajax_array;

    $new_properties = array(
                        '#prefix' => '<div id="contacts-replace">',
                        '#suffix' => '</div>',
                    );

    $form['field_contact']['und'] = array_merge($form['field_contact']['und'],$new_properties);
}


}

function my_callback_function($form, $form_state){
    return $form['field_contact']['und'];
}
?>`

Comment: Entity fields in forms are [interesting](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767) to say the least. Suffice to say you'll probably have more luck with either `$form['field_select_or_other']['und'][0]['#ajax'] = $ajax_array;` or `$form['field_select_or_other']['und'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = $ajax_array;`

Comment: Clive: Thanks for the response but that didn't help really.