# How to integrate some fields into a node more efficient?

Tags: nodes

in my node.tpl.php i want to display a custom field (field_cta) which is part of my page.
It is working this way, but it looks so terrible...is there a drupal command to shorten all the array-walk-trough precedure?

```
if (isset($content['body']['#object']->field_cta['und'][0]['value'])){ print $content['body']['#object']->field_cta['und'][0]['value'];}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's Drupal 7, I think this can works.

```
if(isset($content['fieldname'])):

echo render($content['fieldname']);

endif;
```

Comment: Hi Oskar thanks for your help...you are right...its drupal 7 but $content['field_cta'] does not have any value...does the std.class makes trouble?

Comment: i also don't know why drupal is adding this "und" array...grrr

Comment: @Jurudocs It's the language element of the field, [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784) might help explain it