# problem with hooking node add/edit form

Tags: nodes, ajax, forms, debugging

I wanted to hook `node/add/patient-history` form because I wanted to add ajax in that form.

Before adding Ajax I wanted to **get field names correctly**. So I tried this:

```
function ajaxify_form_patient_history_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_history_patient_id']['und'][0]['#value'] = "Hello";
  // I also tried 
  $form['field_history_patient_id']['#value'] = "Hello";
}
```

They are not working.

I am not sure if I am taking the **field names incorrectly** or **missing something else**.

Hook name seems to be correct because this one works:

```
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Save History');
```

I found some similar questions on stackexchange but with no answers.

Any advice/links appreciated very much. Thank you.

Comment: You can `print_r($form)` to get to know the exact field name.

Comment: That is how I got this name. But this is not working.

Comment: Yes this seems to be proper and I have updated question reasoning why it seems to be proper. Please read the update. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in my module to prepopulate the forms with data when hooking on [FORM_ALTER](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
$form['field_history_patient_id'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = "whatever";
```

But when defining the form it is enough to do :

```
$form['field_history_patient_id']['#default_value'] = "whatever";
```

Comment: Thank you drcelus. This adds the value to the field.  But unfortunately it is not working for adding prefix and suffix. I tried this but not working. `$form ['field_username'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#prefiex'] = '<div id="replace_textfield_div">';` I cant see the div and id added in firebug. It would be great help if you could think of a way to add prefix and suffix too. I could not. Thank you :)

Comment: I see a typo in your code "prefiex". Otherwise maybe you should issue a new question for this.

Comment: Exactly ! How foolish of me !! It was a typo. Works perfectly now :) :) But I still have doubts regarding why these things work differently in different forms.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Why is hook_form_alter so messy in d7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7).

If you have [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module installed, you can check your fields with `dpm($form)` in your hook or you can use `echo '<pre>'; print_r($form); echo '</pre>'`.

I hope this will help you to track down your element hierarchy and find out the correct attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the #default_value property. `$form['field_history_patient_id']['#default_value']`

Comment: I have tried that already. It doesnot work. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: Strange, when I test this it works fine. Try raising your module's weight manually in the system table "UPDATE system SET weight = 20 WHERE name='ajaxify_form'"