# Form - Submit hidden field (select)

Tags: 7, forms

Should be pretty straightforward but I am kinda stuck. I am prepopulating a mandatory field's value according to the URL, so I want to prevent the field from showing up, but not in a CSS level.

hide() and #access do not seem to submit the field leading to a validation error. Any clues on how would I go about doing this?

P.S. not a field of #type => hidden. An actual field. A select list if you want.

Comment trail clarifications:
1) the field is an entity field, a user field
2) the field is mandatory
3) the field is prepopulated using #value and #default_value (for safety (?))
4) the field should not be either visible or editable
5) I'd like to avoid adding a hidden and/or value field myself and write another submission/validation function since the user_register one works just fine. I want to use the value that the field has upon the form's rendering taking into consideration point 4.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want the input to be a hidden element, you don't want it to show on the form, but you want it to be pre-populated from a URL parameter? You're going to have to use CSS I think. Or implement your own pre-populate functionality which converts the relevant field to `#type => value` on the backend, so it never has to be displayed on the form itself

Comment: Yes, the element is a select list, it's prepopulated, but I do not want to show it. If I resign to css, is there any chance I can somehow prevent the user from changing the value?

Comment: If you want to stop the user changing the value then it shouldn't be a select list, you should just convert it to a `#type => value` in your form definition/form alter. That way it will be available server side, can be pre-populated in your form logic, and won't show to the user. Or if you're not bothered about doing it 'properly' just add `#disabled => TRUE` to the element and hide it with CSS

Comment: Hold on, testing.

Comment: Switching #type to 'value' didnt seem to do anything. The select list is visible, usable, and gets submitted.

Comment: just for the record, my custom page callback does a drupal_get_form('user_register_form') on which I am trying to perform the nessecary changes, before returning the form for rendering. Should I be doing this in hook_form_alter instead? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in a form alter. If it's a field as in an entity-field, you'll also need to make sure you're targeting the actual html element, and not the language or delta wrapper...(see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767 for context)

Comment: form_alter is called when I "summon" the form with drupal_get_form. The field is in fact an entity-field, a user field, that is mandatory. Also I am targetting the element itself under 'und' where #type => 'select'.

Comment: @Clive answered it by mixing and matching parts of all replies. See my answer for what actually worked. Any explanation on why/how is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Drupal 7, Field API is in core so you don't have to worry about Fields when editing a node form. In Drupal 6, you have to add an `#after_build` function to do this.

You need to create a [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function to alter the `user_register_form`. (or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)).

I can't remember the structure of form fields. Install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and you can see the entire `$form` array nicely.

```
 <?php
    function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
      dpm($form); // Make sure you have Devel module installed. 
      $field_name = 'field_myfield';
      $value = $_GET['somekey']; // populate this var from the URL params as you mentioned in your question. 

      if (isset($form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0])) {
        if (empty($value)) {
          $form['#access'] = FALSE;
          drupal_set_message(t('Please use correct URL'), 'warning'); // in case the value is not set, hide the form and issue a warning. 
          return;
        }
        // #options is an array like this: array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2'); 
        // Make sure you set the key of this array in $value. if your $value is a value, you'll need to array_flip and find the key instead. 
        $form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#type'] = 'value'; // this element will not be rendered at all
        $form[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#value'] = $value; // this value will be passed to $form_state['values']
      }
    }
```

Calling the form using `drupal_get_form` DOES fire all form_alters as necessary. 
If you are trying to use this form with a direct menu router, set `page callback` in the menu router item to `drupal_get_form` and 
`array('user_register_form'),` as the `page arguments`

Comment: see my answer for what actually worked

Answer (score 0):

For some bizzare reason, both

```
  $form['field_fieldname'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#disabled'] = true;
  $form['field_fieldname'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#type'] = 'value';
```

needed to be done, both in the hook_form_alter.

Doing the same work within the page callback:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('form_id');
//same thing
$form['field_fieldname'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#disabled'] = true;
$form['field_fieldname'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#type'] = 'value';
return $form;
```

Does not work. The field is a select list.

Comment: If anyone, can tell me why those 2 lines work in hook_form_alter, but do not work when I edit the renderable form's array I'd be greatful.