# Drupal 7 hook_fom_alter not working for custom fields

Tags: 7, forms

I have added custom field for email address in my content type.
I want to assigned default email address to this field. Following is my code.

```
function request_order_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'request_order_node_form') {
    dsm($form);
    $form['field_your_email']['#default_value'] = 'sam@gmail.com';
  }
}
```

But I am not getting default value in my field.

Comment: If i add #default_value for Title then its working properly  but if i add the same for my custom field email then its not adding to that element. i checked with dsm also.

Answer (score 2):

Set default value in field setting and try this after that :

```
print $form['field_your_email']; //check where default value is

$form['field_your_email']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'sam@gmail.com';
```

Comment: Thanks its working, but what is the difference between both ?

Comment: Dont know.. just print the form.. :P

Comment: @SumitMadan  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
package :Core
```

in info file, and then write in your module file

```
//first method
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function hook_form_FORMID_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['phone_number']['#title'] = t('Start with + and your country code.');
}

//Second Method--------------------------------------------

function hook_form_alter(&$form,\Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface$form_state, $form_id)   
{
  if($form_id == 'user_login_form')
{

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('name'),
  );
}

if($form_id == 'second_form')  
{
  $form['phone_number'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tel',
    '#title' => t('name'),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You could improve your answer by using code formatting around your code. To do this, either indent each line with spaces or select the entire text and click the code formatting button to do it all at once.