# How do I add a custom validation handler to an existing form/field?

Tags: 8, forms

How do I add a custom validation handler to an existing form (or form field) in Drupal 8?

I have a form that I haven't created. I want to add my own validation rules on some fields when the form is submitted.

For Drupal 7, [Custom validation for a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form) explains to implement `hook_form_alter()` and then add your validation handler][1] to the `$form['#validate']` array, but in Drupal 8 forms are classes. Validation is done through the `validateForm()` method and I don't know how to plug my code into that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom validation for a form?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form)

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate. My question is for D8, your link is for D7.

Comment: I came across this today and just wanted to note for others if you are not using POST (I wanted a URL submission to an existing view page) neither the validateForm nor the submitForm run. In hindsight this is obvious.... but I spent 30 minutes trying to figure it out before I realized.... :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`#validate` property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.2.x#validate) is still used in Drupal 8. (With Adi's solution you will override the existing validator)

If you want to add your custom validator in addition to the default, you will have to add something like this in [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8) (or similar):

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_test_validate';
```

Comment: Thanks, Shabir. So, adding a custom validator works just the same in D7 and D8. ;)

Comment: Exactly, consult code of node module. there are plenty of examples there

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfectly, thank you. Please note that contrary to what the D8 Form API Reference says for `#validate` (your link), you shouldn't use `$form_state` as an array (the D7 way), but as an object implementing `FormStateInterface` (the D8 way). In other words, the code in your custom validator should be analog to the code you'd find in an original `validateForm()` method.

Answer (score 40):

Berdir gave the correct answer, that a constraint is the correct way to go about adding validation to a field in Drupal 8. Here is an example.

In the example below, I will be working with a node of type `podcast`, that has the single value field `field_podcast_duration`. The value for this field needs to be formatted as HH:MM:SS (hours, minutes and seconds).

To create a constraint, two classes need to be added. The first is the constraint definition, and the second is the constraint validator. Both of these are plugins, in the namespace of `Drupal\[MODULENAME]\Plugin\Validation\Constraint`.

First, the constraint definition. Note that the plugin ID is given as 'PodcastDuration', in the annotation (comment) of the class. This will be used further down.

```
namespace Drupal\[MODULENAME]\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * Checks that the submitted duration is of the format HH:MM:SS
 *
 * @Constraint(
 *   id = "PodcastDuration",
 *   label = @Translation("Podcast Duration", context = "Validation"),
 * )
 */
class PodcastDurationConstraint extends Constraint {

  // The message that will be shown if the format is incorrect.
  public $incorrectDurationFormat = 'The duration must be in the format HH:MM:SS or HHH:MM:SS. You provided %duration';
}
```

Next, we need to provide the constraint validator. This name of this class will be the class name from above, with `Validator` appended to it:

```
namespace Drupal\[MODULENAME]\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * Validates the PodcastDuration constraint.
 */
class PodcastDurationConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
    // This is a single-item field so we only need to
    // validate the first item
    $item = $items->first();

    // Check that the value is in the format HH:MM:SS
    if ($item && !preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/', $item->value)) {
      // The value is an incorrect format, so we set a 'violation'
      // aka error. The key we use for the constraint is the key
      // we set in the constraint, in this case $incorrectDurationFormat.
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->incorrectDurationFormat, ['%duration' => $item->value]);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, we need to tell Drupal to use our constraint on `field_podcast_duration` on the `podcast` node type. We do this in `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()`:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;

function HOOK_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if (!empty($fields['field_podcast_duration'])) {
    $fields['field_podcast_duration']->addConstraint('PodcastDuration');
  }
}
```

See official docs at [Defining Constraints (Validations) on Entities and/or Fields.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/entity-validation-api/defining-constraints-validations-on-entities-andor-fields)

Comment: If you end up needing other field values to validate your field you can add a constraint to the content type.  See this blog post: https://lakshminp.com/entity-validation-drupal-8-part-2

Comment: D8 Form Validation API has been explained in detail on Drupal.org here. [Providing a custom validation constraint](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint)

Comment: Since this question is specifically about Form API, not Field API, how does one attach this constraint to a form element (not an entity field)?

Comment: Form elements can't have constraints. You can add validation to a specific form element using #element_validate. See the top answer on this thread - it works the same in D8 as D7 https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86990/adding-validation-to-existing-forms-using-element-validate

Comment: Make sure you check `$item = $items->first();` and return NULL if nothing is there or else you'll get a fatal error when editing the field:

TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::getValue() must be of the type array, null given, called in /data/app/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php on line 407 in Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::getValue() (line 69 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/NestedArray.php).

Comment: When using constraint, how can I rebuild the form? My ajax calls are breaking after form validation.

Comment: Separate issue. Please open a new thread for that.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one. Thanks @Jaypan

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's possible for posters to change it after a period of time, and I answered this well after it was asked.

Comment: In the derrived ConstraintValidator class, how would we access another field. For example if we wanted to do conditional validation?  My example is extending smart_date module whereby for some nodes, I don't yet have a time (it's TBC - to be confirmed) but for others I do. For those TBC, I want to have an additional boolean field, which when checked/ticked (true) the time part of the smart_date field would be set to 00:00 so that smart_date validation passes. The module doesn't currently allow its date-time widget input method to access empty/unset times.

Comment: That's a different question from this topic, and therefore should be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 22):

The correct way to do this for a content entity like node is to register it as a constraint.

See `forum_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()` and the corresponding ? `ForumLeaf` validation constraint (note that there are two classes needed).

That is a bit more complicated at first, but the advantage is that it is integrated into the validation API, so your validation isn't limited to the form system but can, for example, also work with nodes submitted through the REST API.

Comment: Good point: This is something new for who used to write code for Drupal 7. I am sure there are many users who will try adding validation handlers when a constraint is more appropriate.

Comment: Berdir: I did explore this option by trying to implement `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()` (as described [here](https://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-5/issue-2/introducing-drupal-8s-entity-validation-api)) but it never worked... There seems to be a documented problem with this hook: https://www.drupal.org/node/2346347.

Comment: There are some issues but I don't think they are related to your problem. forum.module shows that it works. Share your code, it's not possible to point out possible problems in your implementation otherwise.

Comment: I'd like to go with this method, but until there's a good example of how to use it with data types (i.e. not field specific) to check if some external condition is met, I'm stuck with the form alters.  The article didn't dig into this.  Would someone kindly point me somewhere useful, or post it here?  Thanks.

Comment: what if we need to add existing validation like \Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::validateName(). In d7 it was simple as $form['#validate'] = array(
          'user_login_name_validate',
          'myother_validaion',
        );
But it seems no-contrib module implemented these changes https://www.drupal.org/node/2185941

Comment: @kiranking the user login form is not an entity form, anything you want to do there still needs to be done with plain old form validation and should work exactly like in 7.x

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: It's worth noting that depending on what exactly you want to for entity value validation, using Constraints just isn't possible. For example, I want to validate the value of Field A if Field B was changed as part of the entity update, but Constraints don't have a concept of before-and-after.

Answer (score 14):

I want to add some more light on this matter.
The adding of the validation is exactly the same as before:
in hook_form_alter:

```
$form['#validate'][] = '_form_validation_number_title_validate';
```

The use of the values object inside of the $form_state in the validate function is though a bit different. e.g.:

```
function _form_validation_number_title_validate(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  if ($form_state->hasValue('title')) {
     $title = $form_state->getValue('title');

     if (!is_numeric($title[0]['value'])) {
        $form_state->setErrorByName('title', t('Your title should be number'));
     }

  }
}
```

So not with a direct access to the private variables object, but rather with a getter function.

for more info you can see a full example in my github: https://github.com/flesheater/drupal8_modules_experiments/blob/master/webham_formvalidation/webham_formvalidation.module

cheers!

Answer (score 7):

It is very much the same as in D7. A complete example:

**mymodule.module**:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for the FORM_ID() form.
 */
function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = '_mymodule_form_FORM_ID_validate';
}

/**
 * Validates submission values in the FORM_ID() form.
 */
function _mymodule_form_FORM_ID_validate(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Validation code here
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close. Only the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` needs the form ID. You can have the custom validation function be anything you want. Also, follow the [API guide here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api#fapi-validation) for the proper parameters.

Comment: Before that , how to get the form id as well, where to check this code.

Answer (score 3):

In complement of these good answers I would add :

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'Drupal\your_custom_module_name\CustomClass::customValidate';
```

It is how to call a distant class method for a form validation. 
I think it's better then calling an above function in the module file like in the example given.

Comment: There's no longer a need to jump into procedural code from OO.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> ... adds clientside validation (aka "Ajax form validation") for all forms and webforms using [jquery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). The included jquery.validate.js file is patched because we needed to be able to hide empty messages.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly adding validation callbacks directly to `$form['#validate'][]` simply won't work in case of some forms. Some Drupal forms define their validation handler at **actions > button** form element level.

Example of such form is `language_admin_edit_form` where validation handler can be added this way:

`$form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'callback'`

It is worth to dump and inspect `$form` array inside `HOOK_form_alter()` and verify button element level also.