# Extending the User Registration Form

Tags: forms, users, 8

To add fields to the User Registration one can directly use the **admin/config/people/accounts** page. However, I am required to some other fields to the User Registration like ***food choice*** which is to be selected from drop-down list of foods, ***Email*** and ***Confirm Email*** fields (which should check whether both are same and whether the email was used in db), ***country*** (If UK/US is selected, text field for ***state***, ***postal code*** should appear). Now, I could add the fields to the user registration page, but how can I handle the validations for the fields and how do I show such dropdown list. Am I required to create my module that extends the User Registration form. If so, how do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your only need is to add new required fields to the user registration form, you do not need modify the form through a module; by marking any user entity field as a **Required field** in the field UI, it will be presented in the registration form as a required field for registration.

If you require custom validation that goes beyond "it must be non-empty" you might need to employ a [custom validation handler in a custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183685/how-do-i-add-a-custom-validation-to-an-existing-form-field), another helper module (e.g. [Field validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation)), or a custom field module that matches your use case (e.g. [Address field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/address)).

Comment: So, if I were not to use any external module like Field Validation, should I create a separate module for user registration making own forms with validation.

Comment: Generally, if core/contrib modules don't cover your use case, yes. A custom module would be the route to go to add your own functionality as its needed.