# How do I change template file for the user registration form?

Tags: theming, users

I want to use a different template file for the registration form, but I don't want to use page--user--register.html.twig because in this case I should rewrite all the page structure. We had user-register.tpl.php in Drupal 7, but I couldn't find the theme name in Drupal 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending the User Registration Form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218112/extending-the-user-registration-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://www.foreach.be/blog/how-manipulate-forms-drupal-8
and the file name for overriding the user register form is:
`form--user-register-form.html.twig`

Comment: It depends on what it is you actually want to override but I'ld recommend you'ld rather use `hook_form_alter()` instead. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.3.x for example code.

Comment: @leymannx yeah you are right, but I want to add HTML wrappers to form, and I know I can change field theme with this function.but thanks anyway for your info.