# Setup custom required field validation for a field in custom form

Tags: 8, forms

How can I setup custom required field validation message for a text field in my custom form. I tried below code. But it is not working. It always showing 'Please fill out this field'.

```
$form['first_name'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('First Name'),
  '#default_value' => $this->store->get('first_name') ? $this->store->get('first_name') : '',
  '#required_but_empty' => $this->t('Please enter First Name'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
];
```

Comment: How we will manage clientside validation in drupal 8 form? By using custom jQuery or Drupal 8 has its own way?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I add a custom validation to an existing form/field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183685/how-do-i-add-a-custom-validation-to-an-existing-form-field)

If you want to add your custom validator in addition to the default, you will have to add something like this in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter (or similar):

`$form['#validate'][] = 'my_test_validate';`

Comment: In Drupal 8 client side validation coming by default for form fields.. How can I add additional client side validation to custom form fields?

Answer (score 0):

Set the property "required_error" to form element. This is available in Drupal 8.6. For ex-

```
$form['name'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 60,
  '#default_value' => $form_state->getValue('name', ''),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#required_error' => t('Please select something.'),
];
```

To make this work, firstly you will have to disable HTML 5 validation on the form.

```
$form['#attributes']['novalidate'] = 'novalidate';
```

The property *#required_but_empty* is set automatically during validation when the required field is empty. This is an internal property and is not set manually. It allows #element_validate handlers to set a custom required error message, but without having to re-implement the complex logic to figure out whether the field value is empty.