# Custom validator for checking if fields match

Tags: 8, entities

I have two fields, `value` and `copy` that I'm trying to do some custom validation on to make sure they roughly match each other.

So far in my module I have this:

```
function HOOK_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle)
{
    if(!empty($fields['field_value']) && !empty($fields['field_copy']))
    {
        $fields['field_copy']->addConstraint('CopyMatchesValue');
        $fields['field_value']->addConstraint('CopyMatchesValue');
    }
}
```

A constraint

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MODULE\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * Checks that value matches copy
 *
 * @Constraint(
 *   id = "CopyMatchesValue",
 *   label = @Translation("Copy Matches Value", context = "Validation"),
 * )
 */
class CopyMatchesValue extends Constraint
{
    // The message that will be shown if the format is incorrect.
    public $copyValueMismatch = 'The value does not look like it matches the copy.';
}
```

And a validator

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MODULE\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * Validates the CopyMatchesValue constraint.
 */
class CopyMatchesValueValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint)
  {

      foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
          var_dump($item->value);
      }
      exit;

      // do some processing to make sure they match

      $this->context->addViolation();
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting `$items` to have both fields I added the constraint to, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I pass two fields to one validator so that I can validate them against each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if constraints is the best way to go when you need access to two fields. In your form alter, could you add a custom validation method? That way you would have access to `array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state` giving you access to all fields.

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_test_validate';
```

And then your validation function...

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
function my_test_validate(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Do what you need to do here...
}
```

Comment: I was originally going to do is this way, but then everything I could find said that you should't do it that way and to use constraints instead. If I go this route, how can I then set the errors on the fields with the equivalent of `$this->context->addViolation`?

Comment: Interesting. I haven't heard that this is no longer the route to go. If you have any backup material for that, I would be curious to give it a look.

That said, you can set the error like this...

    `$form_state->setErrorByName('website', $this->t('Invalid URL.'));`

Comment: I framed my code around [this example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/233053/27797) which mentions it, but I found that same sentiment in a few other places as well.

Comment: Ah I see. For an entity, yes that does make sense. I was answering from a custom form approach which is not quite what you intended.

Comment: I'm using this validator on a node_create form, I'm not sure if that matters or not. Is there different validation for entity vs form?

Comment: Well, if you add a custom form validation method, it will only work when that actual altered form is submitted. So if the node is created through an API or programmatically then your validation will be missed. That would be the only concern.

Comment: Gotcha. I think I'd ultimately rather do entity validation if possible, then. But for now I'll do it with forms. Thanks!

Comment: It is totaly possible to add a constraint to the entity level rather than the field level, in that way you can compare two fields during validation.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, in validate() you should get an entity before.
So your code should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MODULE\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * Validates the CopyMatchesValue constraint.
 */
class CopyMatchesValueValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint) {
    $entity = $entity->getEntity();
    $field_first = $entity->get('field_first')->getString();
    $field_second = $entity->get('field_second')->getString();
    if ($some_logic) {
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
    }
  }
}
```

[This](https://makedrupaleasy.com/articles/custom-validator-checking-field-depending-value-another-field) one example how I made a similar custom validator for checking the field depending on the value of another field.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare and validate two fields of an entity you need to add the validation to the entity itself instead of validating individual fields.

If you have a custom entity you built yourself, add the constraint to the annotation:

```
/**
 *[...]
 * @MyEntityType(
 *  id = "myentity",
 *  [...]
 *  constraints = {
 *    "MyConstraintName" = {},
 *  },
 * )
 */
```

If you are altering an entity that you haven't created, you can still add the constraint using `hook_entity_type_alter` or to alter only one bundle of the entity use `hook_entity_bundle_info_alter`

Once you have the constraint set up, you can compare and validate the fields in your constraint validator class "validate" method:

```
  public function validate(array $value, Constraint $constraint) {
   $entity = $this->context->getRoot()->getValue();
   // Do your comparisons here.
   if ($entity->get('yourFirstField')->value !== $entity->get('yourSecondField')->value)) {
     $this->context->addViolation($constraint->fieldsDontMatchMessage);
   }
  }
```