# How should I validate field values against an external service?

Tags: 8, entities

I am looking at how to update a module that validates field values against an external service. Currently, it uses `hook_form_alter()`.

I assumed I should:

1. Write a service that handles external communications and returns a Boolean value
2. Write a [Constraint and a ConstraintValidator](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint) class that uses the service
3. Attach the ConstraintValidator object in `hook_form_alter()`

I assumed I would find a similar implementations in the code of the [ReCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) or [ReCaptcha V3](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha_v3) module. Neither of them uses that approach. I found the [Field Validator](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_validation/-/tree/8.x-1.x/src%2FPlugin%2FValidation%2FConstraint) module that is using constraints.

Is using a constraint validator the correct way, or are there other approaches?

Comment: To be clear, you want to validate the value to be saved in a field using an API that will determine whether or not the given value is valid for that field?

Comment: @Jaypan Yes, basically. Most likely several fields of a couple of different Field types and I did not create these entities or field types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the field value to be validated, I would use a constraint, This ensures that the value is validated regardless of how the field value is saved - whether through a Form, an API (REST/JSON etc) or programatically.

As you didn't create the entities and fields yourself (I'm assuming you mean they're provided by a module or core, and not just that a former developer created them), you'll have to attach your constraint in hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter() as explained in this post: [How do I add a custom validation handler to an existing form/field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183685/how-do-i-add-a-custom-validation-handler-to-an-existing-form-field#answer-233053)

Note however that this will mean anytime your entity has saved, and this field value has changed, your remote API will be called. If this is going to happen regularly, you may want to create some kind of caching system that caches the responses from the remote API.

Comment: Thanks for the mention that the constraint will be used even if the API is called.