# Set minimum commerce product price

Tags: commerce, 9

I want to set a minimum price that can be entered in the product add/edit form of Commerce.  If users enter a lower price, an error should be displayed, when they click on the save button.

I am using the following code to achieve that.

```php
function THEME_form_commerce_product_default_add_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = '_custom_formvalidation_number_price_validate';
}
    
function _custom_formvalidation_number_price_validate(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($form['variations']['widget']['entity']['price']['widget'][0]['#default_value'] = ['number' => 2,'currency_code' => 'EUR'] > 2) {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('price', t('The price must be at least 2'));
  }
}
```

I need to check the entered value, not the default value. Which element is that exactly?

Comment: You should write a simple module containing your custom validation function. The module should also contain a 'hook_form_alter' function that targets your form, and adds a reference to your validation function to form's the '#validate' array. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183685/how-do-i-add-a-custom-validation-handler-to-an-existing-form-field https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-02-11/form-custom-validation-after-hook

Comment: This is very helpful but I still can't set a minimum price value.