# comment form custom validation

Tags: comments, forms

I am using a custom validation in my Drupal 7 comment form.
I want to match the `comment_body` against a word `"example"` so if someone just type `"example"`in the comment body then it will show a error message that only the word `"example"` is not allowed. After reading drupal api documentation i codded like this:

```
function mango_form_comment_node_news_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $form['comment_body']['#prefix'] = '<div class="sm">Post your comment now!</div>';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Post Your Comment';
    $form['#validate'][] = 'banana';
}

function banana($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['comment_body'] == "example") {
    form_set_error('comment_body', 'Your comment can not contain example!');
  }
}
```

Do not working `:'(` what i'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784), and then inspect the `$form` to find the exact element you should be referring to (probably something like `$form_state['values']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']`)

Comment: Thank you @Clive your answer on that post really help me to understand the array's.

Answer (score 0):

The values for comment_body is not stored in $form_state but in something like:

```
$form_state['values']['comment_body']['und'][0]['value']

function banana($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['comment_body']['und'][0]['value'] == "example") {
    form_set_error('comment_body', 'Your comment can not contain example!');
  }
}
```