# How do I use hook_form_alter() to add CSS classes to a custom input field in user_register_form?

Tags: forms

I want to add a CSS class to the input element of a custom field in my user_register_form.

This is the field markup.

```
<div class="field-type-text field-name-field-personal-best field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper"
 id="edit-field-personal-best">
<div id="field-personal-best-add-more-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-personal-best-und-0-value">
        <label for="edit-field-personal-best-und-0-value">Personal Best </label>
        <input class="text-full form-text" id="edit-field-personal-best-und-0-value"
               name="field_personal_best[und][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my implementation of `hook_form_alter()`, which doesn't work. Changing the submit button works, but adding a CSS class to that input element doesn't.

```
function em_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('GO!'); // Change the text on the submit button
    $form['edit-field-personal-best']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'timepicker hasDatepicker';
}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use the HTML ID of the element you're interested in as the identifier in PHP - not quite how it works.

For a field API field, that will look more like:

```
$form['field_personal_best'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'foo';
```

Your mileage will probably vary there, have a read of [Why is hook_form_alter() so messy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7) for some relevant information, and make sure you have the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) installed to help with debugging (`dpm($form)` will tell you pretty much everything you need to know).

Comment: Thanks mate, that helped, spent so much time yesterday trying to figure this out. 

Btw i have devel installed but  (dpm($form) doesnt work as im not logged in when checking register page. Or am i doing that wrong too.

Comment: Ah ok, if this is a dev site you can set a permission for anon users to see Devel output - don't enable it on a production site though, and remember to turn it back off again (or ideally uninstall Devel altogether) when you go live