# add class to fields on login block

Tags: theming, blocks

I am using drupal 7 and would like to customise my login form block.

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
```

if ($form_id == "user_login_block") {
        $form['links'] = Null; // Remove Request New Password and other links from Block form
        //$form['links']['#markup'] = t('Forgotten Password?') . ' [' . t('Forgotten Password?') . '](/user/password)'; // Remove Request New Password from Block form
        //$form['links']['#markup'] = ' ' . t('Register') . '' . ' ' . t('Forgotten Password?') . ''; // Remove Request New Password from Block form

```
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="nano-ui">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['name']['#attributes']['class'][]= array("nui-input");




    $form['name']['#title'] = Null; // Change text on form
    $form['name']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('username'));
    $form['pass']['#title'] = Null;
    $form['pass']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('password'));


}
```

}

In the above code the following line does not seem to have any effect on my field :

```
$form['name']['#attributes']['class'][]= array("nui-input");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what will work

```
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="nano-ui">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

   $form['name']['#title'] = Null; // Change text on form
    $form['name']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('username'));
    $form['pass']['#title'] = Null;
    $form['pass']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('password'));

    $form['name']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'nui-input';
```

Here is the reference : [How do I use hook_form_alter() to add CSS classes to a custom input field in user_register_form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106032/how-to-use-form-alter-to-add-class-to-custom-input-field-in-user-register-form)

Comment: Please mark it as answered if it helped.

Comment: Hi tried cleared the cache and unfortunately it did not work

Comment: Updated my answer. The order of statements matter. $form['name']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('username')); is replacing the complete attributes array and the changes made to the array before that will have no effect. Add the class after the setting the attributes array.