# Cannot set form #default_value when altering Views Exposed Filter forms

Tags: 7, hooks

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message($form_id);

  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $options = array(
      'All' => t('All'),
      '$' => '$',
      '€' => '€',
      'тг' => 'тг',
    );

    $form['field_price_second']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['field_price_second']['#options'] = $options;
    $form['field_price_second']['#default_value'] = '$';
    $form['field_price_second']['#size'] = 1;
    $form['field_price_second']['#validated'] = TRUE;

    dpm($form);
  }
}
```

However, the default value isn't working, i see instead 'All' value as default in my views exposed form's select list. What's wrong?

DPM output:

[image]

Comment: Fields in forms are a special case - see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784

Comment: I just pasted my DPM output and i don't think it's my case. I have only a single revision of each of my fields.

Comment: Ah ok it's an exposed filter form, yeah that's a different thing altogether. In my experience it's very hard to alter those using `hook_form_alter()`, you usually need to override validate/submit handlers and massage the form state. I edited the question title to make it more specific, hope that's ok

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the whole element, like this:

```
...
if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $options = array(
      'All' => t('All'),
      '$' => '$',
      '€' => '€',
      'тг' => 'тг',
    );

  $form['field_price_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => '$',
    '#size' => 1,
    '#validated' => TRUE,
  );

    dpm($form);
  }
 ....
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @Heihachi ok, I understand.. i posted my answer right before you edited your question.. I thought the element is a different type, not selectlist..

Comment: As you can see in DPM it shows overrided #default_value, but on my actual exposed form it still shows "All". I have no idea, it is overriding it somewhere? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Heihachi What is the initial state of element.. Can you show the DPM output of initial state, with `#options` expanded?

Comment: Sure, http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/6145/iw3w.png

Comment: @Heihachi Is this the first state which had been rendered by Views?

Comment: That's it. All is the first state

Comment: @Heihachi They are absolutely the same.. What are you altering then? Is `Remember the last selection` option not checked?

Comment: It's not checked. By default: value - All is selected, i want it to be a "$" sign, got it? :)

Comment: @Heihachi There is something wrong with your views configuration, I think.. Here is my exposed element config: `Operator: Is equal to`, `Value: ''` (empty value), options are not checked, then I am altering the form with `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` function (`mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)`) and I can change whatever default value, which I wish, e.g: `$form['field_adv_cat_1_tid']['#options']['All'] = t('--Выберите');
    $form['field_adv_cat_1_tid']['#default_value'] = 2679;`.. It works fine.

Comment: $form['field_adv_cat_1_tid']['#default_value'] = 2679; does that work for you?

Comment: If i want to choose "$" as default value - do i have to put it as a first element in my $options array?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13581/discussion-between-heihachi-and-xurshid29)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue. I had to set:

```
$form_state['input']['field_price_seconds'] = NULL;
```

Only after that i could see my #default_value

Spoke too soon, when i set this up - even if i change the value it reverting back to a default one.