# Is it possible to change the field type in a node form afterwards?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have an instance here where an existing textfield in a node form should be limited to enter only three possible values. I though it might be possible to alter the field to #type => 'select' and attach my '#options' as well. So I altered the form to:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'MYCONTENTTYPE_node_form') {
    // dpm($form);
    $form['field_MYFIELD']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['field_MYFIELD']['#title'] = 'Enter a value';
    $form['field_MYFIELD']['#options'] = array(
      1 => 'Value 1',
      2 => 'Value 2',
      3 => 'Value 3'
    );
  }
}
```

But when I now try to create a form like that, all I get is this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in /Users/Shared/www/drupal.dev/includes/common.inc on line 6606
```

Is it even possible to change an existing field type like I want with a small custom module? Do I have to alter the submit function then as well? Please help!

Comment: Have a read through [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/), it's likely you need something more like `$form['field_MYFIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#type'] = 'select'];`, etc

Comment: @Clive - Thank you a thousand times! I still was in the container ... Should I delete this question or attach the correct code in an answer?

Comment: I think an answer with the code you used would be useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: Yes! It is possible. All I did wrong when altering the form is that I changed the `'#type'` of the container instead of changing the type of the textfield itself. I had to go one level deeper:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'MYCONTENTTYPE_node_form') {
    // dpm($form);
    $form['field_MYFIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['field_MYFIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#options'] = array(
      1 => 'Value 1',
      2 => 'Value 2',
      3 => 'Value 3'
    );
    // #select doesn't need #size and #maxlength
    unset($form['field_MYFIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#size']);
    unset($form['field_MYFIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#maxlength']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that pesky `value`; I am always perplexed when I work with Form API as to which level attributes and other options should be changed on, even after a decade of Drupal development :P

Comment: I used you sample but in setting default_value, I have problem. although I set #default_value but there is no item selected in rendered field.

Comment: @leymannx Is this the same goes to drupal8 as well? I'm trying to convert select type field to 'textfield' by using $form['field_control_number'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#type'] = 'textfield'; but not working. Any idea on what is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a field formatter that will render select box for this field. It's very simple and didn't take many time to use it. API here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7

I can help with this if you need.