# Get submitted value of a select list error on #options - Drupal 7

Tags: webforms

I have seen this block of code in a few places as the correct method:

```
$selected_index = $form_state['values']['select_field'];
$display_value = $form['select_field']['#options'][$selected_index];
```

So here is my code for it:

```
$key1 = $form_state['values']['field_setup_time3'];
$reservationStartPadding = $form['field_setup_time3']['#options'][$key1];
```

But I get this error with my code:

```
Notice: Undefined index: #options in ... blah blah blah
```

I am using a List (integer) running a select list with 4 options in it. Is options not the right choice here? I just need the numerical value from the user selected dropdown list when they submit the calendar booking.

Thanks!

Comment: when you use the Devel module and `dpm()` every variable you've created ... what do you see ? For example in your code add: `dpm($selected_index);dpm($display_value);dpm($key1);dpm($reservationStartPadding);` ... i bet you something has a `value` you've assumed is a Number, but is something else (the string `#options`).

Comment: After installing devel read [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784), it should help to explain why the options aren't where you're trying to find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to tenken and Clive I was able to figure it out.

```
$key1 = $form_state['values']['field_setup_time3'];
```

This line outputted as a string. Since I was only using integers in my select list, the label and key value were the same. I removed both lines of code and replaced it with this (after some playing around with devel):

```
$reservationStartPadding = $form_state['values']['field_setup_time3']['und'][0]['value'];
```

This outputted the value as a number and not as a string. I was able to use it from there in my future code correctly.