# Removing required attribute on user entity fields not working

Tags: users, entities

I have added fields to user entity and make them required and show on registration page. So the user signing up have to fill all the fields. On the admin side these all fields are coming but i don't want to make them required when admin is creating any user. I thought it will be solved if i `hook_form_alter`  the user registration form and remove the `#required` attribute. I did this for admin and `dpm($form)`. I set `#required => 0` also `unset #required` but it keep on showing error of required field. I uncheck the required checkbox in field settings from admin panel and it does not show validation errors on both Admin and Frontend.

What i want is when admin create a user he just enter username and password and leave the rest of custom fields blank and it should register the user. But on the frontend users have to fill the whole form.

Below is the code:

```
    // If this is admin creating user
     foreach($form as $key => $value){
                if(strpos($key, 'field_') !== false){
                    $value['und']['#required'] = 0;
                    unset($value['und']['#required']); // This isn't working either
                }
            }
    // Endif
```

Updated Full Code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function paypal_signup_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form'){
      global $user;
      if(!in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))){
        //Submit handler for redirecting user to Paypal.
        $form['#submit'][] = '_paypal_signup_redirect_paypal';
    } else {
        // Remove validation when admin is creating user.
        foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {
            if (strpos($key, 'field_') !== FALSE) {
              $form[$key][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
              $form[$key][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#required'] = FALSE;
            }
         }
        dpm($form);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has [`element_children()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/element_children/7) to help you safely loop over render arrays. Looping over such arrays manually will inevitably causes problems. Your code should look more like this:

```
foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {
  if (strpos($key, 'field_') !== FALSE) {
    $form[$key][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#required'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Incidentally, your current code doesn't work because you're modifying a variable that has only ben declared within that function's private scope.

Comment: but i dpm the $form after this loop and for every custom fields my code removed the #required key.

Comment: Which is what you asked for...and if not, are you saying that the change you've made in the loop are not being persisted immediately _after_ the loop? I highly doubt that, but if so it indicates you have a problem with your PHP installation. That isn't standard behaviour

Comment: I tried your code and its not working. By the way in dpm i don't see [LANGUAGE_NONE] any where. The structure i am gettting is `key => array ('etc..','und' => array('#required => 1'));`

Comment: `LANGUAGE_NONE` == `'und'`. I'm afraid I can't debug your site from here, you'll need to do that yourself. If you have more information about the problem, just edit the question. This code example is based on the assumption that you've already identified exactly where in the form array you need to manipulate the `#required` property. If you haven't already identified that, again you'll need to do so and update the question with those details

Comment: What i personally think is that the #required attribute for the form is removed with my code but there is some other #required thing in the field_api system. Since the #required is removed from the FAPI.

Comment: I am updating the screenshot of dpm. please wait.

Comment: You've got that wrong - `hook_field_widget_form()` is invoked for the fields (by `field_attach_form()`), and only then is the form sent for altering. So unless you have another, non-core, module affecting the `#required` attribute after your form_alter has run, the changes will definitely persist. That's what you need to establish, really

Comment: I think you are saying right :S i was about to send you screenshots of before and after loop dpm. But when in the loop i am setting it to `false` or `0` its not changing. However if i unset the #required it got vanished from the `und array`. So may be unsetting does not make the `#required = false ?`

Comment: It might be something else - read [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7) and see if that helps explain it

Comment: Your code is setting #required to False for each field but on submit form i get the required field errors :(

Comment: In my `hook_form_alter` i took `&$form` as param. Is this wrong ?

Comment: No that's fine. Might be a good idea to edit the question and post the whole code, would be easier to spot errors that way

Comment: i've updated the full function. The dpm below my foreach tells that the #required = FALSE on both.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem - function signature needs to take `$form` by reference: `function paypal_signup_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { `

Comment: I removed it just for try. I put it by reference and still getting required errors

Comment: I tried with 0 and false both. But even the form isn't submitted the * signed shows on all of the custom fields. Which means they are still required BEFORE and AFTER the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing any custom code, I think you should try [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) Module and in addition [Profile2_regpath](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) Module provides you some Extra Options

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with textfield. Drupal put the textfield added through GUI under a container and the rendered arrays look like this:

```
Array
(
    [#type] => container
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field-type-text
                    [1] => field-name-field-first-name
                    [2] => field-widget-text-textfield
                )

        )

    [#weight] => 5
    [#tree] => 1
    [#language] => und
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [#entity_type] => user
                    [#entity] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [uid] => 0
                            [hostname] => 0.0.0.0
                            [roles] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => anonymous user
                                )

                            [cache] => 0
                        )

                    [#bundle] => user
                    [#field_name] => field_first_name
                    [#language] => und
                    [#field_parents] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#columns] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => value
                            [1] => format
                        )

                    [#title] => First Name
                    [#description] => 
                    [#required] => 1
                    [#delta] => 0
                    [#weight] => 0
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [#entity_type] => user
                            [#entity] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [uid] => 0
                                    [hostname] => 0.0.0.0
                                    [roles] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1] => anonymous user
                                        )

                                    [cache] => 0
                                )

                            [#bundle] => user
                            [#field_name] => field_first_name
                            [#language] => und
                            [#field_parents] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [#columns] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => value
                                    [1] => format
                                )

                            [#title] => First Name
                            [#description] => 
                            [#required] => 1
                            [#delta] => 0
                            [#weight] => 0
                            [#type] => textfield
                            [#default_value] => 
                            [#size] => 60
                            [#maxlength] => 255
                            [#attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => text-full
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [#theme] => field_multiple_value_form
            [#field_name] => field_first_name
            [#cardinality] => 1
            [#title] => First Name
            [#required] => 1
            [#description] => 
            [#prefix] => 

            [#suffix] => 

            [#max_delta] => 0
            [#after_build] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_form_element_after_build
                )

            [#language] => und
            [#field_parents] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [#access] => 1
)
```

The [`element_children()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/element_children/7.x) doesn't help as it is not recursive. It loops only the immediate children whereas the textfield is rendered with three/four levels deep of arrays. The solution was to add this:

```
unset($form['field_first_name']['und']['#required']);
unset($form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['#required']);
unset($form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#required']);
```