# Drupal rendering Custom Element children

Tags: entities

Here is the complete code of element info

```
function MyModule_element_info() {
  $types['my_element'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#process' => array('module_element_process'),
    '#theme' => array('module_element_theme'),
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
    '#config' => array(
      'module' => 'some_module',
      'params' => array(),
    ),
    '#default_value' => -1,
  );

  return $types;
}

function module_element_process($element, &$form_state, $complete_form) {
      $element['my_element']['input_hidden'] = array(
    '#type'                    => 'hidden',
    '#value'                   => '',
    '#attributes'              => array('class' => array('hidden-field')),
    '#validate'                => array(),
      );
}

function theme_module_element_theme($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  return '<div>' . drupal_render_children($element) . '</div>';
}
```

It output the field as

```
 field_webform_group[und][0][my_element][input_hidden]
```

Why is the und(undefined) showing in the form field?

If I have multiple child to render how to output  the child fields?

```
 '<div>' . drupal_render_children($element['input_hidden']) . '</div>'.
 '<div>' . drupal_render_children($element['input_select']) . '</div>';
```

How do I process the element value on submit?

Thanks

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7/27784#27784

Comment: @Clive is it possible to process the value on submit. I need to save the value in another table. Not has node entities