# PlaceHolder in comment Form

Tags: comments, forms

I want to add a placeholder to my all comment form , here is what i did :

**template.php**

```
function ThemeName_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
        // HTML5 placeholder attribute
        $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Serach ...');

    }


    switch ($form_id)  {
        case 'comment_form':
            $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Name' );
            $form['subject']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('Subject'));
            $form['comment_body']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('comment'));

            break;
    }

}
```

nothing happend , Any Help ?

Thanks

**Update**
Finally i could add placeholder to comment form like this

```
function sizin_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    $form['author']['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Name' );
    $form['author']['name']['#title']= FALSE;

    //Subject
    $form['your_comment']['subject'] = $form['subject'];
    $form['your_comment']['subject']['#title'] = FALSE;
    $form['your_comment']['subject']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('title'));
    unset($form['subject']);
    $form['your_comment']['subject']['#weight'] = -10;

    //Comment
    $form['your_comment']['comment_body'] = $form['comment_body'];
    $form['your_comment']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('comment'));
    unset($form['comment_body']);


}
```

But i couldn't add to textarea(comment Body) ? AnyHelp ?

Comment: Read through [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy-in-d7), it has the answer in a round about way

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get the point

Comment: Comment body is a field, so you need to target the _element_, which will be further down the array. Maybe something like `$form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = 'foo';`

Comment: so if i was wrong about the body field , the others not working ?

Comment: here is my comment name property : comment_body[und][0][value]

Comment: added this but nothing happend : $form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('comment'));

Comment: Can you confirm the `$form_id` you are checking is correct? Because for me id is `comment_node_page_form` and not `comment_form`. Try to `dsm` inside and outside `if {}`.

Comment: @sumitMadan Yes here's what i get after dpm($form) in form_comment_form_alter : #id (String, 12 characters ) comment-form

Comment: @Clive updated my question please see this

Comment: @sumitMadan updated my question please see this

Comment: What!!! by setting the title to false??? Well I think that is not the solution. It seems issue with your CSS. Can you please check the CSS after changing your code to previous state?

Comment: no without setting the title to false it's working @SumitMadan
Problem is Comment Body

Answer (score 1):

Reading through Placeholder module I come to know this

> Once FAPI uses HTML5 to render elements, this module can be replaced
>   by the "placeholder" attribute available as part of the HTML5 spec.
>   You can update the FAPI to use the "placeholder" attribute right now
>   by using [elements module](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements). This means that this module is only useful
>   if you are concerned about older browsers that do not support
>   "placeholder".

try using elements module so the support for HTML5 attribute can become available in your installation.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1995746) is the way to add default placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @[tonystar](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/48904/tonystar)

Instead of:

```
$form['your_comment']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('comment'));
```

add this:

```
$form['your_comment']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('comment');
```

Comment: Please add some more info: is this code a part that should be replaced? Or new code that should be placed instead of... what? And how did it help, exactly?

Comment: updated my answer , please see this : i've asked my question one more time : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163312/alter-comment-body-in-comment-form/163326?noredirect=1#comment197013_163326

Answer (score 0):

Install [Placeholder Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/placeholder)

Then you can use

```
$form['name']['#placeholder'] = t( 'Name' );
$form['subject']['#placeholder'] = t('Subject');
$form['comment_body']['#placeholder'] = t('comment');
```

Comment: That won't work! It will for name/subject, but not for the field. You need to attach the property to the form element, which is further down

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to use module for that