# Setting #title or #description in node_form_alter

Tags: forms

I have have a field of type container that is acting as a title field, see complete definintion below.

My issue is that I cannot seem to modify the title or description via form_alter, I have tried the following approaches:

```
$form['title_field'][$language->language][0]['#title'] = $form['title_field'][$language->language][0]['#title'] . t(' (maximum @max characters)', array( '@max' => $maximum_program_title_limit));
```

And also:

```
$form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#title'] = $form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#title'] . t(' (maximum @max characters)', array( '@max' => $maximum_program_title_limit));
```

I tried both "language" options, and also tried at one higher level of the array:

```
$form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#title'] = $form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#title'] . t(' (maximum @max characters)', array( '@max' => $maximum_program_title_limit));
```

None of these take effect on the form, although other changes are actually done on the form in this same function.

```
Array
(
    [#type] => container
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field-type-text
                    [1] => field-name-title-field
                    [2] => field-widget-text-textfield
                )

        )

    [#weight] => -5
    [#tree] => 1
    [#language] => und
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [#entity_type] => node
                    [#entity] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [vid] => 27
                            [uid] => 1
                            [title] => program 2-11
                            [log] => 
                            [status] => 1
                            [comment] => 0
                            [promote] => 0
                            [sticky] => 0
                            [nid] => 13
                            [type] => program
                            [language] => und
                            [created] => 1440515144
                            [changed] => 1440515144
                            [tnid] => 0
                            [translate] => 0
                            [revision_timestamp] => 1440515144
                            [revision_uid] => 1
                            [body] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [field_ambassadeurs_ambassadors] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [field_organization_organisation] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [target_id] => 2
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [field_participant_reg] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [registration_type] => participant_participante
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [field_prog_attachment] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [field_program_template_ref] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [target_id] => 11
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [title_field] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [value] => program 2-11
                                                    [format] => 
                                                    [safe_value] => program 2-11
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [title_original] => program 2-11
                            [translations] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [original] => 
                                    [data] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                (
                                    [rdftype] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => sioc:Item
                                            [1] => foaf:Document
                                        )

                                    [title] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => dc:title
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [created] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => dc:date
                                                    [1] => dc:created
                                                )

                                            [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                            [callback] => date_iso8601
                                        )

                                    [changed] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => dc:modified
                                                )

                                            [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                            [callback] => date_iso8601
                                        )

                                    [body] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => content:encoded
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [uid] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => sioc:has_creator
                                                )

                                            [type] => rel
                                        )

                                    [name] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => foaf:name
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [comment_count] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => sioc:num_replies
                                                )

                                            [datatype] => xsd:integer
                                        )

                                    [last_activity] => Array
                                        (
                                            [predicates] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => sioc:last_activity_date
                                                )

                                            [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                            [callback] => date_iso8601
                                        )

                                )

                            [name] => admin
                            [picture] => 0
                            [data] => b:0;
                            [date] => 2015-08-25 17:05:44 +0200
                            [revision] => 1
                            [menu] => Array
                                (
                                    [link_title] => 
                                    [mlid] => 0
                                    [plid] => 0
                                    [menu_name] => main-menu
                                    [weight] => 0
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [module] => menu
                                    [expanded] => 0
                                    [hidden] => 0
                                    [has_children] => 0
                                    [customized] => 0
                                    [parent_depth_limit] => 8
                                )

                        )

                    [#bundle] => program
                    [#field_name] => title_field
                    [#language] => und
                    [#field_parents] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#columns] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => value
                            [1] => format
                        )

                    [#title] => Additional title ( optional ) (maximum 50 characters)
                    [#description] => This field is optional, any text entered here will be added  between parenthesis after the default program title shown above. (maximum 50 characters)
                    [#required] => 
                    [#delta] => 0
                    [#weight] => 0
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [#entity_type] => node
                            [#entity] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [vid] => 27
                                    [uid] => 1
                                    [title] => program 2-11
                                    [log] => 
                                    [status] => 1
                                    [comment] => 0
                                    [promote] => 0
                                    [sticky] => 0
                                    [nid] => 13
                                    [type] => program
                                    [language] => und
                                    [created] => 1440515144
                                    [changed] => 1440515144
                                    [tnid] => 0
                                    [translate] => 0
                                    [revision_timestamp] => 1440515144
                                    [revision_uid] => 1
                                    [body] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [field_ambassadeurs_ambassadors] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [field_organization_organisation] => Array
                                        (
                                            [und] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [target_id] => 2
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [field_participant_reg] => Array
                                        (
                                            [und] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [registration_type] => participant_participante
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [field_prog_attachment] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [field_program_template_ref] => Array
                                        (
                                            [und] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [target_id] => 11
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [title_field] => Array
                                        (
                                            [und] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [value] => program 2-11
                                                            [format] => 
                                                            [safe_value] => program 2-11
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [title_original] => program 2-11
                                    [translations] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [original] => 
                                            [data] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rdftype] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => sioc:Item
                                                    [1] => foaf:Document
                                                )

                                            [title] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => dc:title
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [created] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => dc:date
                                                            [1] => dc:created
                                                        )

                                                    [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                                    [callback] => date_iso8601
                                                )

                                            [changed] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => dc:modified
                                                        )

                                                    [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                                    [callback] => date_iso8601
                                                )

                                            [body] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => content:encoded
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [uid] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => sioc:has_creator
                                                        )

                                                    [type] => rel
                                                )

                                            [name] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => foaf:name
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [comment_count] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => sioc:num_replies
                                                        )

                                                    [datatype] => xsd:integer
                                                )

                                            [last_activity] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => sioc:last_activity_date
                                                        )

                                                    [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                                    [callback] => date_iso8601
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [name] => admin
                                    [picture] => 0
                                    [data] => b:0;
                                    [date] => 2015-08-25 17:05:44 +0200
                                    [revision] => 1
                                    [menu] => Array
                                        (
                                            [link_title] => 
                                            [mlid] => 0
                                            [plid] => 0
                                            [menu_name] => main-menu
                                            [weight] => 0
                                            [options] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [module] => menu
                                            [expanded] => 0
                                            [hidden] => 0
                                            [has_children] => 0
                                            [customized] => 0
                                            [parent_depth_limit] => 8
                                        )

                                )

                            [#bundle] => program
                            [#field_name] => title_field
                            [#language] => und
                            [#field_parents] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [#columns] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => value
                                    [1] => format
                                )

                            [#title] => Additional title ( optional )
                            [#description] => This field is optional, any text entered here will be added  between parenthesis after the default program title shown above.
                            [#required] => 
                            [#delta] => 0
                            [#weight] => 0
                            [#type] => textfield
                            [#default_value] => program 2-11
                            [#size] => 60
                            [#maxlength] => 60
                            [#attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => text-full
                                        )

                                    [maxlength_js_label] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Content limited to @limit characters, remaining: <strong>@remaining</strong>
                                        )

                                )

                            [#maxlength_js] => 1
                        )

                    [#maxlength] => 50
                    [#maxlength_js] => 1
                    [#attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [maxlength_js_label] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Content limited to @limit characters, remaining: <strong>@remaining</strong>
                                )

                        )

                    [#prefix] => <div id="title_prefix"><strong>Default program title:</strong> template 1</div>
                )

            [#theme] => field_multiple_value_form
            [#field_name] => title_field
            [#cardinality] => 1
            [#title] => Additional title ( optional ) (maximum 50 characters)
            [#required] => 0
            [#description] => This field is optional, any text entered here will be added  between parenthesis after the default program title shown above. (maximum 50 characters)
            [#prefix] => <div id="title-field-add-more-wrapper">
            [#suffix] => </div>
            [#max_delta] => 0
            [#after_build] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_form_element_after_build
                )

            [#language] => und
            [#field_parents] => Array
                (
                )

            [#maxlength] => 1
            [#maxlength_js] => 1
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                    [maxlength_js_label] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Content limited to @limit characters, remaining: <strong>@remaining</strong>
                        )

                )

        )

    [#access] => 1
)
```

I would like to know what is missing for this form_alter to work as should?

Comment: It's probably `$form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#title']` or `$form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['value']['#title']` (I never remember which 'til I get there)

Comment: Thanks Clive. Awesome. It is $form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#title'] , if you add answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form element itself is a bit further down the array:

```
$form['title_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#title']
```

See [Why is hook_form_alter() so messy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy/27784#27784) for a bit of background