# validation of a Content type field

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I'm trying to validate a field of a content type.

I've tried different approaches like with `hook_form_FORMID_node_form_alter()`, `hook_field_validate()` and even with the Field validate module.

The value of the field should only be alphabetic. So no spaces or special characters.

Here are the functions that I've tried:

***Form validation***

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORMID_node_form_alter()
 */
function birthday_form_colleague_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'birthday_slackhandle_validation';
}
/**
 *  Validation function
 */
function birthday_slackhandle_validation($form, &$form_state) {
  //for the field_colleague_slack_handle field
  $slacknaam = $form_state['values']['field_colleague_slack_handle'];
  //$special_character_list = '\'^£$%&*()}{@#~<>,|=_+¬-[\Ò]';
  //$pattern = '[a-z]';
  if (preg_match('[a-z]', '$slacknaam')) {
    form_set_error('field_colleague_slack_handle', t('not a valid slackname'));
  }
}
```

***Form rule***

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_alter
 */
function birthday_form_colleague_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_colleague_slack_handle']['#rules'] = [
    [
      'rule' => 'alpha',
      'error' => 'Not a valid slack name.',
    ],
  ];
}
```

***Field validation***

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_validate().
 */
function birthday_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
  //for the field_colleague_slack_handle field
  $special_character_list = '\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-[\Ò]';
  if (preg_match('/' . $special_character_list . ']/', $field['field_colleague_slack_handle'])) {
    form_set_error('field_colleague_slack_handle', t('not a valid slackname'));
  }
}
```

The form rule and field validation did absolutely nothing.
The form validation did react, but the same as the field validation module: it accepts EVERY character or none (none if i try `!preg_match`...)

Comment: `if (preg_match('[a-z]', '$slacknaam')) {` It seems you are not using a variable but a string, so the outcome will always be the same.

Comment: @Neograph734, yes I've put this in a single quoted string because if I just put the variable there it gives an error : ***Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string***

Comment: You can use a variable as the subject for preg_match ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)). If that gives an error, your input `$form_state['values']['field_colleague_slack_handle']` might not be string?

Comment: @Neograph734 the `$form_state['values']['field_colleague_slack_handle']` comes from a content type form form drupal. It's a textfield. 
So it should be a string not ?

Comment: Nope it'll be an array - `$form_state['values']['field_colleague_slack_handle'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]` or `$form_state['values']['field_colleague_slack_handle'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` may well be a string though. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767

Comment: @clive, tried it again, it worked ! Also fixed my regex