# How to use autocomplete text field in fieldset?

Tags: ajax

I want to use a textbox with autocomplete features. I have gone through the drupal form API and found the solution at [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#autocomplete_path).

It's working fine if I am using this directoly in the form fields. But it's not working if I am using this any ***Field collections*** item in profile2 fields.

I am using ***profile2*** fields with fieldscollection and following is my code.

```
/*profile_2_type is id for profile 2 module and it's not working for me*/    
$form['profile_2_type']['field_test_auto_cmplete']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/autocomplete';

/*Here is the code which is working for me for node fields */
$form['title']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/autocomplete';
```

Comment: Read through [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy/27784#27784), your issue is almost certainly related

Comment: finally got the solution
here is updated code

$form['profile_2_type']['field_test_auto_cmplete']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/autocomplete';

and "user/autocomplete" only works for admin users

Answer (score 2):

finally got the solution
here is updated code

```
$form['profile_2_type']['field_test_auto_cmplete']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'user/autocomplete';
```

and "user/autocomplete" only works for admin users