# I am trying to modify a form element using hook form alter but I can't find the correct field name

Tags: 7, forms

[image: my code creates a new date element instead of modify the original element]I am learning Drupal 7. I have a custom module, trying to modify a date form element in my page. I have the form id identified, and Devel module list me all the fields in this page, I think I am typing the correct field name but it doesn't work, It creates a new form element instead of modify the form element.
Maybe the element is inside a fieldset, but I don't know how to write the correct line to modify. It is a datepicker and I am trying to modify the minDate property for the date element.

Here is my code:

```
function davidcustom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message($form_id);  // print form ID to messages

  // Check when the right form is passed
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_24296') {

    $form['field_line_item_fecha_reserva'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Pick the desired date'),
      '#type' => 'date_popup',
      '#datepicker_options' => array(
        'minDate' => 10,
      ),
    );


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you can't find an array key, the best thing to do is to dump the entire form array and search for it. If you use the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel), you can use the following:

```
dpm($devel);
```

This will give you a nice collapsible output through which you can search. Or you can use the old-school method that I use, and dump it directly using:

```
die('<pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

Comment: How can I know if my field is inside a fieldset, and then I have to include too the fieldset in my line of code to identify the form element?

Comment: Dig through the output and you can find it whether it's in a fieldset or what not. Also, what you have done in your original code is create a new form element. You just need to alter the elements that you want to change.

Comment: What is the code to only modify 'minDate' => 10 in my form element?

Comment: `$form['field_line_item_fecha_reserva']['#datepicker_options']['minDate'] = 10;`

Comment: It's more complicated then that with fields, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/why-is-hook-form-alter-so-messy

Comment: Thanks for the `die...print_r` trick. `dpm()` was hanging my browser because of a large `$form` object.